# Ubuntu Server: Change Hostname Error

Tags: hostname

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 fresh installation where I want to change the 'hostname' (machine name'. I have followed several instructions, such as from:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/03/change-hostname-computer-name-ubuntu-11-04-natty/

but all of them end with 'Cannot Open Display' problem. Basically, I have a GUI (desktop) installed. I switch to the Terminal by CTRL ALT F2 key and run commands.

What is happening? Am I missing some package? Note, I can do the `stat` command on `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` files so perhaps Permissions are okay?

Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty old, for 11.04 Natty.  I think we have a newer guide around here... let me see if I can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are following that guide it tells you to open gedit. gedit needs a GUI environment to work. So you have two options (personally I don't see why you go to Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get to the terminal, but anyway)

1. Stay in GUI and run the commands via the gnome-terminal (just press the Windows-key and type terminal)
2. After pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2, replace "gksu gedit" with "sudo vim" or "sudo nano"

Comment: Doing 'sudo nano' did the trick! ('sudo vim' did not work). And good tip about the Windows  to get to the Terminal. Much better. Thank you very much!